# Prove Redundancy of an Expression

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I can explain it to myself verbally pretty well, but I'm really struggling with "proving it" to myself through logic operations.

How can I, with some more ands and ors and iffs in-between,  prove that:
$x \notin B \vee(x \in B \wedge x \in C) \iff x \notin B \vee x \in C$
Or in other words, that the "$x \in B$" in there is redundant?

As I said, I can "explain" it to myself with some pretty artistic hand-waving and I'm pretty sure it's true, but I can't seem to express it. (If it's not in B then the expression is true because of $x \notin B$ regardless of anything else, so I wouldn't even care about the parentheses unless $x \in B$, at which point I just need to know if it's in C as well. But how do I "say that with operators"?)

Comment: Thanks in advance!
(Also: my vocabulary is very limited when it comes to math in general and to set theory in particular, so please do feel free to adjust my wording where necessary.)

Comment: Any reason you can't just use a truth table?  That would count as a proof.  Otherwise, look at the distributive properties of $\land$ and $\lor$ for the left side of your statement.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to avoid using a truth table in this case. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Rule_of_replacement) and [conjuction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination) and [introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_introduction).
\begin{align*}
x \not \in B &\vee (x \in B \wedge x \in C)  \\
    &\iff (x \not \in B \vee x \in B) \wedge (x \not \in B \vee x \in C)  &  &\text{distributivity}  \\
    &\implies x \not \in B \vee x \in C  &  &\text{conj. elim.}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
x \not \in B &\vee x \in C  &  &  \text{Given.}\tag{1}  \\
x \not \in B &\vee x \in B  &  &  \text{Prop. of set membership}  \tag{2}  \\
(x \not \in B &\vee x \in B) \wedge (x \not \in B \vee x \in C)  &  &  \text{conj. intro. (2) and (1)}  \\
x \not \in B &\vee (x \in B \wedge x \in C)  &  &  \text{distributivity}  \\
\therefore x \not \in B &\vee x \in C \implies x \not \in B \vee (x \in B \wedge x \in C)
\end{align*}

An alternative is by enumerating the truth table:

- $x \in B$, $x \in C$: The left-hand side is $\text{False} \vee ( \text{True} \wedge \text{True})$, which is True, and the right-hand side is $\text{False} \vee \text{True}$, which is True.  So equivalence is not rejected in this case.  (We abbreviate the evaluations in the subsequent cases.)
- $x \not \in B$, $x \in C$: left: True, right: True.  Equivalence is still not rejected.
- $x \in B$, $x \not\in C$: left: False, right: False.  Equivalence is still not rejected.
- $x \not\in B$, $c \not\in C$: left: True, right: True.  Equivalence is still not rejected.

Since equivalence is not rejected in all cases, equivalence holds.

Comment: You're missing the fact that $(x\notin B)\lor (x\in B)$ is true, leaving $\iff x\notin B \land x \in C)$.  This proof can be completed with $\iff$ all the way...

Comment: @amWhy : The fact you recite is used explicitly to eliminate the true clause.  What is not used is the falsehood "conjunction elimination is a biimplication", because I have seen many students fail to grasp the difference between the usage you are recommending and the variant that would be used above.  One could patch this with an extra step and introduction of a truthy literal.  I didn't.

Comment: Because the user asked for a proof based on equivalencies, and conjunction elimination only permits implication.  Ex. $A \land B \to B$ is true, but $A\land B \not\equiv B$

Comment: @amWhy : OP made no such request.

Comment: @amWhy : Also, repeating what I said improves nothing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Eric and amWhy! Your answers as well as your discussion in the comments (and specifically the highlighting of the differences in your respective answers) was really enlightening.

Comment: I did not repeat what you said, Eric Towers.  You took a very labored way, and never explained that $x \notin B \lor x \in B$ is a tautology.  Sorry, if you were concerned about young students, you would have pointed this out.

Answer (score 4):

$$x \notin B \vee(x \in B \wedge x \in C) \iff \underbrace{(x\notin B \lor x \in B)}_{\text{tautology}} \land (x\notin B \lor x\in C\tag{distribution}$$

$$\iff \top \land (x\notin B \lor x \in C)$$

$$\iff x \notin B \lor x \in C$$

Comment: I marked Eric Tower's answer because it introduced me to several concepts that helped me wrap my mind around things; but I want to thank you specifically because the concise nature of your answer as well as its simplicity make it really easy to understand, and because your comment on Eric's answer was really informative, too.

Comment: +1 I don't see what's wrong with this answer, even if I don't quite like the use of distributivity of $∨$ over $∧$.

Comment: @ShyGuy: Note that distributivity of $∧$ over $∨$ should be intuitively natural, because if A and ( B or C ) holds, then of course ( A and B ) or ( A and C ) holds. Distributivity of $∨$ over $∧$, which is what amWhy is using here, is less intuitive, but can be obtained easily if you think of $∧,∨$ as $\min,\max$ (of truth-values) respectively, with $1$ for true and $0$ for false. This also is helpful in understanding the duality in boolean algebra.

Comment: @user21820 Thanks for that :) I took some time reading these answers after they were posted to think about them in an attempt, indeed, to get an intuition for why this is all true, and I'm really glad I did! It's been very helpful. I hadn't considered the min/max perspective, though; that's really interesting!